# Is it possible to link to apps in Ubuntu Software Center?

Tags: software-center

I would like to link to software(to mention them in a blog post, for instance) present in the Ubuntu Software Centre - how can I do so?

Is there any alternative besides [AptURL](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two main options:

- Linking to the [online version of the Sofware Centre](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/oneiric/gimp/)
- Using [apt.ubuntu.com](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gimp) links, which can be easily generated from within the Software Centre, as shown below (note that this option is essentially AptURL, but with a 'normal' URL)

[image: SCreenshot]

Answer (score 9):

Yes, you can link in your blog http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/'package' (where package is a Ubuntu package available on the repos.

For example linking in http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gedit in your blog would install the package `gedit` if the user clicking the link would be using Ubuntu and create a fault message "You need to be running Ubuntu to install this package" (if I can remember) if you are using another operative system.

[image]